# Semi-interdependant Jovian Colony

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, jupiter, lunar-base

Given the low $\Delta v$ needed to transfer between the moons of Jupiter even just between the Galilean large moons, and the distribution of heavier molecules and atoms towards the inner system (Io + ice ring), and the lighter in the outer system (Calisto + outwards):
A crewed colony on an outer moon with some ice easily harvested for the colony, but shipments of autonomously mined resources like sulphur, iron, etc. transported by Nuclear-Electric (r similar) tug systems.

This would allow for a crewed scientific outpost, whilst not worrying about ultra-thick rad-shields for the habitat.

**Would this theoretically (100years in the future) work, independently of the feasibility of Earth/Jupiter transfer windows?**

I am aware that this would depend on ISRU being advanced enough etc., but humour me...

Comment: This is likely one of those questions that will be marked as too broad, but I will give you some quick things to consider. 1). The Galilean moons are a prime place for ITN-style low energy transfers. 2). Most of the resource exchange will be between Io and the other 3 moons. 3). Io would be a miserable place to set up a mining base, due to the extreme radiation and volcanism. 4). Jupiter and its moons are actually quite expensive to get to from earth and other planets owing to its large gravitational well, so some degree of resource sufficiency is necessary.

Comment: Hey cheers man, if I can find a way to make it less broad I'll do so.
Oh and if you feel like narrowing it down yourself you have my express permission.

Comment: @AntiElonGuy I think that if you focus on 1 issue or key factor of setting up mining bases on the moons of Jupiter, then it would be less likely for the question to be closed as too broad. Right now you are just asking if it is possible to do so which can only be answered by opinion. While if you asked, so there is this problem and how could it be solved, then it will most likely stay open.

Comment: I think this question has a good premise, so I will not vote to close it.

Comment: It's a bit of a curse of these ISRU for far-future colonies-type questions, I'm afraid. It's incredibly speculative, because we simply don't know what parts of the process will be easy and which will be hard. For instance, what are the structural properties of ice at -200 degrees in a vacuum and a high-radiation environment? Can you make useful mechanical parts out of that? What admixtures do you need before you can make such parts?

Comment: Just fyi I'm a big fan of these sorts of questions, and am eager for more authoritative answers. I just know from experience that some of the more shall we say 'stickler' types are uncomfortable with anything that can't be answered with a clear mission profile.

Comment: @Ingolifs I fully agree. I also like these types of questions about the future, but it is really hard to give a non-opinion answer to such types of questions.

Comment: Narrowing the question might help non-futurist, stuck-in-the-present people like myself understand what exactly it is that we are wondering if it will work. Is it a question of whether it is possible to live on the outer moons of Jupiter where the radiation is reduced and ice is available, which is made possible by autonomously harvesting resources from the inner moons which are not available on the outer moons, thus eliminating the need for miners to work in the more dangerous inner moon region?